# C - String Linked List

Tags: c

I need to take the following code, and modify it to accept strings as arguments, instead of ints.  In the end, I need the program to take all command line arguments, and add them to a linked list of strings.

So if the input was six seven eight, when i printed the linked list, it would print: eight seven six.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct iNode
{
    int myInt;
    struct iNode* next;
} IntNode, *IntNodePtr;

IntNodePtr insert(int i, IntNodePtr p)
{
    IntNodePtr newp = malloc(sizeof(struct iNode));
    newp->myInt = i;
    newp->next = p;
    return newp;
}

printlist(IntNodePtr p)
{
    if(p == NULL)
        printf("\n");
    else
    {
        printf("%d ", p->myInt);
        printlist(p->next);
    }
}

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 5;

    if(argc > 1)
    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    IntNodePtr iNodeList;
    iNodeList = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    while(i < n)
    {
        iNodeList = insert(i++, iNodeList);
        printf("List is now: ");
        printlist(iNodeList);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: read the [SO FAQ on asking homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: The solution is pretty simple, just change int to char *, a couple of tweaks here and there you should get the solution. I have no problems with homework because mike is actually learning something. I only have problems with people who get paid for coding and demand on here for full source code. Mostly without googling. Mike you dont want to be this kind of a guy. So you should always first try solving problems by yourself. :) We are always here to help if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: @Reno - That's why I was so skeptical about what the problem was. The OP seems to know exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If printing the solution backwards is the problem, just maintain a global head ptr that points at the first iNode. When you have to print, while(headPtr.next !=null){ printf(...); }

Answer (score 0):

I think your question relates to the order of items in the list.

Consider that, with linked lists, it is possible to add items to the head, to the tail, or insert them at an arbitrary place.

Look at the insert() function, it adds new items where?

Simplistically, you can just reverse the order in which you insert items.  In real life that probably won't go down too well.

Maybe maintain a tail pointer?
And write an addItemToTail() function?

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about pointers and memory. Good place to learn that is [Stanford CS Education Library](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/). You'll find there also nice materials about linked lists.